# bash heredoc hangs when more than 512 characters

Tags: bash, heredoc

my gnu bash scripts
GNU bash, version 5.1.0(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0)
on macos hang when they contain a heredoc with greater than 512 characters,
e.g. the USAGE heredoc below works unless I add 1 more character to it

```
cat <<'USAGE'
        --all       List all tasks, TASK_IDs will be ignored
        --name NAME Only list tasks with specified NAME
        --logs      list log messages
        --pending   Only list tasks that have not been scheduled
        --active    same as --pending
        --scheduled Only List tasks that have been scheduled, whether running or finished
        --running   Only List tasks that are currently executing / running
        --finished  Only List tasks that have been run, i.e., have finished
12345678901234567890 
USAGE
```

note: there are no variable expansions, quotes, etc. just literal text.
If i break all of the text into multiple heredocs they all work ... but if i combine them in anyway to create a heredoc with >512 characters bash hangs
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this on 5.1.0(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0). Here's what I tried: 1. Copy your script to a file `foo`, 2. Add a line "foobar" before `USAGE`, 3. Run `bash foo`. The script writes the data to stdout as expected

Comment: interesting, thanks for the feedback
but ... it fails on my system. btw, i didn't post my macos version:
19.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Thu Oct 29 22:56:45 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.141.2.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
maybe that is the problem?

Comment: moreover, i've had a number of shell scripts with 'USAGE' messages over the years and never noticed this problem until recently.

Comment: What a strange construction just to echo a string. Why don't you simply use `echo` followed by a string over several lines enclosed into quotes?

Comment: Currently experiencing this with `GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin21.1.0)`

Comment: I am experiencing this on MacOS 12.7.1 with brew installed GNU Bash 5.2 -- reboot fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Well - the problem has disappeared. Maybe related to recent bash upgrade to

GNU bash, version 5.1.4(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0)

which did have changes to heredoc processing related to size of heredoc wrt buffer sizes.

Comment: Sigh, I was wrong. The problem persists. Not sure why it appeared to disappear the other day.

Comment: You ever fix this? It just started happening to me.

Comment: Actually, the problem just disappeared for me. The scripts that were experiencing this issue just started working. So if there is an underlying problem I haven't been able to isolate it.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing recently started happening to me. I recognize that this isn't a very satisfying answer, but I just switched back to bash `3.2.57(1)-release`, that comes pre-installed with mac. (I spent several hours trying to figure out how to use homebrew to rollback to an earlier version of bash, but, as of 2020, this no longer seems to be a supported feature.)

I ran `chsh -s /bin/bash`, to change my default shell to the Mac-default bash.

I then then re-arranged my path so that it would find `/bin/bash` before `/usr/local/bin/bash`. (If a script has a `#!/usr/bin/env bash` shebang, it finds the older version.)

Answer (score 0):

I have encounter the same issue. With help of a colleague we trace a quite odd behaviour in one of our tools to this exact issue, when the string to pipe into <<< exceeds 512 characters the command hangs.

We both have the same environment, it works for him it does not for me.

macOS Catalina 10.15.7
Bash installed with brew
Bash version GNU bash, version 5.1.8(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0)
Kernel Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0

When using Mac included Bash it works (GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19) but I cannot use that version.

This is driving us nuts.

Comment: Reboot fixed my issue. This is crazy. Sorry I do not know the real cause.

Comment: You can edit your question to include the reboot fix, rather than comment.

Answer (score 0):

Experienced this with bash `version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin21.1.0)` and fixed via reboot.

Answer (score -3):

This is not really an answer to the question but a suggestion to simplify the code:

```
echo "
        --all       List all tasks, TASK_IDs will be ignored
        --name NAME Only list tasks with specified NAME
        --logs      list log messages
        --pending   Only list tasks that have not been scheduled
        --active    same as --pending
        --scheduled Only List tasks that have been scheduled, whether running or finished
        --running   Only List tasks that are currently executing / running
        --finished  Only List tasks that have been run, i.e., have finished
12345678901234567890 "
```

It will do the same but in a easier way.

Comment: I often have to run 3rd-party scripts that contain heredocs (which are a pretty common way of interacting with bash stdin), so "just don't use heredocs" isn't really a solution for me. The `cat << EOL ...` construction above is really more of a minimalist reproduction of the issue.

Comment: Exactly. Moreover, there are constructs allowed within heredocs that are not allowed within quoted text so they are not equivalent.